# How to integrate a PDE?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How does one integrate this PDE with respect to $x$? $$u\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+ u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}=0$$

My idea is to rewrite this equation as follows:

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial t}+ \frac{1}{3}\frac{\partial u^3}{\partial x}+\underbrace{u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}}_\text{don't know how to rewrite this}=0$$

So I could integrate the 2nd term to get $\frac{u^3}{3}$, but I don't know what to the with the other two terms. I'd appreciate some hints.

Comment: You could integrate by parts; that brings the gap in the derivatives down to $1$ in the new integral which lets you use the trick you just used in the second term.

Comment: How about dividing this equation by $u$ first and integrate.  But what good can come out of integrating this whole thing, when you will end up with the partial derivative with respect to $t$ of the integral of $u$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: @Batominovski, as per the hint provided, I need to first multiply the equation by $u$, integrate it, and then manipulate it using the product rule. So I've already multiplied the original equation by $u$. I think this should be a definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I'm also given that all $x$-derivatives of $u$ go to $0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: OK, in that case $\int_{-\infty}^\infty u u_{xxx} dx = u(\infty) u_{xx}(\infty) - u(-\infty) u_{xx}(-\infty) -\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_x u_{xx} dx$, and you can handle the last integral using tricks you already used.

Comment: @Ian, how did you arrive to the RHS from the LHS?

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: How do we know if $u(\infty)u_{xx}(\infty) = 0$? $u_{xx}$ goes to $0$, but we don't know if $u(\infty)$ can "win over" $u_{xx}$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: @sequence It's valid for **solitary** solution.

Comment: @NgChungTak, sorry, what's a solitary solution?

Comment: @sequence This is a variation of **KdV equation** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation  which has a single wave packet solution called **soliton**.  See also the WolframAlpha solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bu%5Bx,t%5D,t%5D%2Bu%5Bx,t%5D+D%5Bu%5Bx,t%5D,x%5D%2BD%5Bu%5Bx,t%5D,%7Bx,3%7D%5D%3D0

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the wide question "how to integrate the PDE ?". 
This is only the answer to the question " how to rewrite $u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}$ ?" in order to integrate it relatively to $x$. 
$$u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \right) - \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)^2 \right)$$
$$u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)^2 \right)$$
This is of no help to find the general solution of the PDE (See the references given by Ng Chung Tak in the comments).

Comment: Can you please clarify how you derived $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \right) - \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ from $u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}$?

Comment: $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \right)=u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ Can you take it from here with my above answer ?

Comment: Yes, I figured out yesterday that what results is $uu_{xxx}$ and two mutually cancelling terms. I was wondering, however, how your thought process worked. Did you immediately see that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ leads to the above and then to the final result with the preceding $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}? What I mean is that it does seem like there's a specific technique involved here, but rather some kind of "reserve engineering", if you know what I mean.

Comment: Just looking at $u\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}$ it is obvious that this term appears in the differentiation of $u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ . Of course an additional term appears which have be cancelled. If by chance this additional term is an exact derivative, then the goal is reached.